# ASP.Net MVC-5 Active Directory Sync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have an ASP.Net MVC-5 application which currently uses ASP.Net Identity 2 OWIN for authentication. It enables me to create users internally within the application and assign them roles. I now need to add an option to add a user from Active Directory, and when the user logs in to the application if their application profile says they have been added using active directory to authenticate using LDAP.

I see the problem statement and Use case being as follows...

1. Connect to Active Directory and query for users based on domain username.
2. Add a user from Active Directory into the application, mark the users application profile as an active directory user.
3. When a user logs into the application detect if they are an active directory user using their profile `isLDAP` flag and use the appropriate role provider.

I have trawled the web and come across several solutions but they mostly relate to ADFS authentication which is built into ASP.Net Identity 2.

I came across this article on how to do everything with Active Directory but it is nearly 10 years old http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

I also found this article which is from 2009 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/all-operations-on-active-directory-ad-using-C-Sharp/

For me to come up with a quick solution I am reaching out to the community for assistance and guidance in this particular aspect of the web application.

C#er